# Arithmetic operation so that 0, 1, & 2 return 0 | 3, 4, & 5 return 1, etc

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I'm trying to take 9x9, 12x12, 15x15, etc. arrays and have the program interpret them as multiple 3x3 squares.

For example:

```
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0
0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 9
```

Will be understood as:

```
0 0 1 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 2 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 3 0
------+-------+------
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 6 0 0
0 0 4 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 5 | 0 0 0
------+-------+------
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 7 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 8 0 | 0 0 9
```

Where:

```
"1" @ [0][2] is in box "[0][0]"
"2" @ [1][5] is in box "[0][1]"
...
"6" @ [3][6] is in box "[1][2]"
...
"9" @ [8][8] is in box "[2][2]"
```

.

I can use `row % 3` and `column % 3` to determine the row and column values within the box, but how can I determine which box a given value in the array is stored in?

This formula could be used in a method such as the one below.

```
public int[] determineCoordinatesOfBox(int rowInArray, int columnColumnInArray) {
    // determine row value
    // determine column value

    // return new int[2] with coordinates
}
```

It seems possible and I've been beating my head over this. Perhaps I'm making a simple problem too difficult?

Many thanks for the help!

- Justian

Comment: Aye as said below if you use the / operator on Integers it will work fine.  For example Row 2 and Column 3 would be Box[0][1] (numbering colums and rows from 0). This seems to be what you want.

Comment: This is so ridiculously simple. I was looking for a formula when I should have been looking at beginner integer concepts >>

Comment: If you can't even figure this one out any more, I'd suggest quitting coffee and getting some sleep ;)

Comment: I don't drink coffee. And it's only 11pm here. I'm just jetlagged is all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `/` operator:

```
box[0] = rowInArray / 3;
box[1] = columnInArray / 3;
```

Comment: add a `min` to that and you'll be fine (it's not going to be in box 3.6666 x 2.3333).

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my question correctly. (
0/3 = 0 = 0 |
1/3 = 0.33 = 0 | 
3/3 = 1 = 1 | 
4/3 = 1.33 = 1)

Comment: If they're ints, then 2 / 3 == 0.  If it's a float or double, you'll have the expected problem.

Comment: Wait. Wait. Wait. I think I see what you're saying. Hold on... Wow. It's far too late here. I skipped 2. Yes. You're right. I *really* overcomplicated this. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm really gonna regret asking this question in the morning. This is such a beginning programming concept. I blame the jet-lag :P

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it's just simple integer division.

Since you're coding Java (it would be the same in at least C, C++ and C#), it's simply `/` operator:

```
int rowInArray = 3;
int columnInArray = 7;

int boxY = rowInArray / 3;    // will evaluate to 1
int boxX = columnInArray / 3; // will evaluate to 2

int rowInBox = rowInArray % 3;       // will evaluate to 0
int columnInBox = columnInArray % 3; // will evaluate to 1
```

Just keep both the arguments of division integer - `7 / 3` is `2`, but `7 / 3.0` or `7.0 / 3` will be `2.5`.